# how to remove the default control buttons from a windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, controls

The image describes what I am trying to do.

I have a "connect four" game which works perfectly well but I want to remove the default buttons provided at the top right hand corner of the window. Any quick help on this?

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to that?

Comment: @hege imagine a case with multiple form; and you don't want that the user close a child form, leaving the main form hidden and still running.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ControlBox` property of Forms does this after hiding the Minimize and Maximize buttons.

[MSDN - Form.ControlBox Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.controlbox.aspx)

Answer (score 10):

[Click here to view steps in video](https://youtu.be/_l74Vix_MqA)

**Please Set ControlBox Value as "False" of your desire form.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the properties window for your form designer, there should be a listing for MaximizeBox and MinimizeBox that you can set to false to disable the maximize and minimize buttons on the form. AFAIK there is no way to disable the close button.

Comment: yep ControlBox property does that